# Find String from string in java

Tags: java

I have one String "1,3,5,7,9,11,12,14" and I want to check whether the string contains "12,3,14," or not in java.

My code:

```
String str1 = "1,3,5,7,9,11,12,14";
String str2 = "12,3,14,";

if(str1.contains(str2)){
                System.out.println("Found!");
}
```

Comment: you already know it. Then whats the question ?

Comment: @MSach - In str2, the numbers are not in order

Comment: You have to use `split()`, split the string and then check if each string in str2's array is present in str1's array

Comment: @TheLostMind thanks then question is not clear. With your clarification i explained what he needs to do.

Answer (score 4):

I think the question that you want to ask here is:

> How to check if an array consisting of String values separated by a comma(,) consists of all the values of another array that are also separated by a comma(,).

If that's the case, then you can't use `contains()` method because that serves a different purpose.

Just define your own method (for example: `containsValues()` here). And define the suitable logic:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "1,3,5,7,9,11,12,14";
        String str2 = "12,3,14,";
        if (containsValues(str1, str2)) {
            System.out.println("Found!");
        }
    }

    public static boolean containsValues(String str1, String str2) {
        String strArr1[] = str1.split(",");
        String strArr2[] = str2.split(",");
        return Arrays.asList(strArr1).containsAll(Arrays.asList(strArr2));
    }
}
```

**Output**

> Found!

Comment: `"12,3,14,".split(",")` results array `[12, 3, 14, <empty>]`, so `containsAll` will return false.

Comment: No @SashaSalauyou. I think you are mistaken. `split()` doesn't create that empty slot. It only returns `[12, 3, 14]`. You can do a simple `System.out.println("12,3,14,".split(",").length);` to verify it. You'll get the output as `3`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't see any problem in your code. You are not getting `Found!`, because str1 actually does not contain `"12,3,14,"`.

```
    String str1 = "1,3,5,7,9,11,12,14";
    String str2 = "12,3,14,";
    String str3 = "1,3,5";

    if (str1.contains(str2)) { //false
        System.out.println("Found!");
    }

    if (str1.contains(str3)) { //true
        System.out.println("Found!");
    }
```

But if you want to find them individually in `str1`, you may split your `str2` and find them one by one.

```
    String str1 = "1,3,5,7,9,11,12,14";
    String str2 = "12,3,14,";       
    String s[] = str2.split(",");

    for (String str : s) {
        if(str != "" && str1.contains(str))
            System.out.println(str+ " found!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
String stack = "1,3,5,7,9,11,12,14";
String needle = "12,3,14,";

return Arrays.asList(stack.split(","))
       .containsAll(Arrays.asList(needle.split(",", 0)));
```

Notice usage of `0` in `String#split()` to discard empty trailing substring in malformed `needle`.

Answer (score -1):

explore [String java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) . There is `split()` method to do this

1. split the second string with delimiter as comma
2. Then check if every element is contained in source or not